# JDialog loads and causes session reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I tried to use JQuery JDialog to show some information to users, however, when the dialog loads, it somehow reset the session of current user. When I comment "return false;" line. A page is loaded with the info, and the session is sill there.

I looked around the how to solve this problem, but I have not found any solution. Anyone could help please.

html:

```
$('.skill_ajax').click(function() {
    var url = this.href;
    var dialog = $('<div style="display:hidden"></div>').appendTo('body');
    // load remote content
    dialog.load(
        url,
        {},
        function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            dialog.dialog();
        }
        );
    //prevent the browser to follow the link
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I solved it problem, I just removed the empty brackets.

```
$('.skill_ajax').click(function() {
var url = this.href;
var dialog = $('<div style="display:hidden"></div>').appendTo('body');
// load remote content
dialog.load(
    url,        
    function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        dialog.dialog();
    }
    );
//prevent the browser to follow the link
return false;});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this:

```
$('.skill_ajax').click(function(event) {
    var url = this.href;
    var dialog = $('<div style="display:hidden"></div>').appendTo('body');
    // load remote content
    dialog.load(
        url,
        {},
        function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            dialog.dialog();
        }
        );
    //prevent the browser to follow the link
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

`return false` has always felt like a hack to me in this context, especially because there is a method that is made specifically for this use, `preventDefault()`.

Comment: Thank you bircker for suggestion, but it actually open a page with information. The dialog message appeared but it disappeared suddenly before reload the page.